# Video in compositor not showing in render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, chromakey

The video I am trying to key will not show in the renderer. It shows just fine in the viewer node, as well as in the preview on the composite node. I have looked online for solutions already:

Use nodes is on.
Transparent is checked.
Nothing loaded in VSE.
Only 1 (default) render layer exists in the project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's a "Use Sequencer" checkbox that must be unchecked - even if you have nothing loaded in there it will overwrite your frames with the black output from sequencer

Comment: That solved it, thank you